# Delete subtable from a table, SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

What is the most clever way to delete tuples from table1, that are in the second table,
if the second table is not a part of initial database, but a result of some really big query?

```
table1           *this table is a result of some query
-------------    -------------
| id1 | id2 |    | id1 | id2 |
-------------    -------------
| 1      2  |    | 5      6  |
| 3      4  |    | 1      2  |
| 5      6  |    | 11     12 |
| 7      8  |    -------------
| 9      10 |    
| 11     12 |
| 13     14 |
-------------
```

I came up with

```
delete from table1
where id1 in (select id1 from (         really long query to get a second table))
  and id2 in (select id2 from (the same really long query to get a second table));
```

It works, but I feel like I'm doing it way too wrong, and not keeping the query DRY.

And would the way you suggest work the same if table1 had an additional column, for example "somecol"?

Comment: Standard SQL would allow `where (id1, id2) in (select id1, id2 from ...)` don't know if SQLite allows that too

Comment: unfortunately no, I get "near ",": syntax error: ", but I'll try to remember this practice.

Comment: I suggest you to use `EXISTS` instead ;).

Comment: @shA.t maybe i'm doing it wrong, but it erased all the tuples from table1.

Comment: @OccamRazor: Never run a DELETE without checking if it deletes the correct data by changing `DELETE` to `SELECT * FROM`... You probably forgot to add the correlation.

Comment: @dnoeth I just dont save the changes, and reload the database. I see yours and shA.t's answers. I'm trying to implement it for my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, You can use [`EXISTS`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/exists.php) statement like this:

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (<your long query>) AS dt
    WHERE table1.id1 = dt.id1
      AND table1.id2 = dt.id2);
```

**[[SQL Fiddle Sample]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/81039/5)**

Comment: Can you please explain what `select 1` means?

Comment: When you use `EXISTS` statement it will be true when there is at least one row in the results, and columns are not important, so I use an untitled column with a fixed value of 1 as it is  recommended ;).

Answer (score 1):

A Correlated Subquery using `EXISTS` allows matching multiple columns:

```
delete 
from table1
where exists 
 ( select * from 
    (
      "really long query"
    ) as t2
   where table1.id1 = t2.id1 -- correlating inner and outer table
     and table1.id2 = t2.id2 -- similar to a join-condition
 )
```

Comment: tried multiple times, carefully watching for every parentheses and commas, and every time I get "near "as": syntax error: "

Comment: @OccamRazor: You probably can't use an alias in SQLite like this, edited my answer...

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `with`, `delete` and `exists`:

```
with secondtable as (
      <your query here>
     )
delete from table1
    where exists (select 1
                  from secondtable st
                  where table1.id1 = st.id1 and table1.id2 = st.id2
                 );
```

Comment: I've been looking something like `with ... as ...` for my other queries.